# dump returned values as expanded array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, var-dump

I am using `dump($value)` function. I have an associative array with lots of entries in it. I need to see the values right away without having to click the expansion button when dumped. I can use `var_dump()` to see it right away but I like it more using dump because it is modern and interactive. Below is the snapshot of dump function:

[image]

Comment: Using another formatting tool could always help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141585/a-more-pretty-informative-var-dump-alternative-in-php

Comment: you could devise something that will make it collapse in default in this thread https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/the-new-dd-in-laravel-5-is-kind-of-shitty?page=1 or just use the ol' `echo '<pre>', print_r($value, 1), '</pre>'; die;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick format tool, no need to use laravel: ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141585/a-more-pretty-informative-var-dump-alternative-in-php))

```
$pretty = function($v='',$c="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",$in=-1,$k=null)use(&$pretty){$r='';if(in_array(gettype($v),array('object','array'))){$r.=($in!=-1?str_repeat($c,$in):'').(is_null($k)?'':"$k: ").'<br>';foreach($v as $sk=>$vl){$r.=$pretty($vl,$c,$in+1,$sk).'<br>';}}else{$r.=($in!=-1?str_repeat($c,$in):'').(is_null($k)?'':"$k: ").(is_null($v)?'&lt;NULL&gt;':"<strong>$v</strong>");}return$r;};

echo $pretty($array);
```

Here's a screenshot of sample output, as well. (Bonus points for figuring out what the data is)
[image: screenshot of output]

Comment: thank you. this is what I need. Though I want the way dump is designed, but I can always add simple styles to make it prettier.

Answer (score 23):

the simple tip is: CTRL+click.

Comment: Works. In some case we will have to CTRL+click twice.

Comment: Cmd+click on macOS.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the JavaScript you can put after the `dump()`:

```
var compacted = document.querySelectorAll('.sf-dump-compact');

for (var i = 0; i < compacted.length; i++) {
  compacted[i].className = 'sf-dump-expanded';
}
```

Credits go to [Curtis Blackwell](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/expanding-dd-vardumper-by-default?page=1#reply=139959)

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($results);
echo '</pre>';
```

or more easy way is just

```
var_dump($results);
```

Answer (score 1):

Inject this script in Browser with help of the temper monkey chrome extension and add the script for that web page where you want to do that...

```
let all_dumps = document.getElementsByClassName('sf-dump-note');
for(let i = 1 ; i < all_dumps.length ; i ++ ) {
    all_dumps[i].click();
}
```